# Js call function with arguments

Tags: javascript, html

I have created 4 buttons and every button with its own id and I have a function that displays the given element id. so I want to apply it on all this 4 buttons. what did I do wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<button id='b1'>Click</button>
<button id='b2'>Click</button>
<button id='b3'>Click</button>
<button id='b4'>Click</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
function show_id(element){
    alert(element.id)
}

for(i=0; i!=document.getElementsByTagName('button');i++){

    target = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[i]
    target.onclick = show_id(target)

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use class instead of id.

Comment: would it make any different ?

Comment: You probably meant `i!=document.getElementsByTagName('button').length`. As it stands, you're comparing a number to an HTMLCollection, potentially creating an infinite loop, only stopped by the error it creates inside the loop.

Comment: i've changed it, now they all alert the last button id !

Comment: Go with `for(let i=0`

Comment: still the same results

Comment: wait so you would like that the button which was pressed do the alert?

Comment: yes every button get clicked shows its id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as below -

```js
function show_id() {
  alert(this.id)
}

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].onclick = show_id;
}
```

```html
<button id='b1'>Click</button>
<button id='b2'>Click</button>
<button id='b3'>Click</button>
<button id='b4'>Click</button>
```

Passing arguments to onclick event -

Using `HTML` -

```js
function show(element, value) {
  console.log(element.id);
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<button id='b1' onclick='show(this, "a")'>Click</button>
```

Using `JS` -

```js
function show(value, event) {
 console.log(value);
 console.log(event.target.id);
}

var button = document.getElementById("b1");

button.onclick = show.bind(this, "a");
```

```html
<button id='b1'>Click</button>
```

But, as mentioned by @connexo, use `addEventListener` to bind DOM events.

Comment: is it necessary to write (element) after the function ?

Comment: @badr, No, not required. I have removed it.

Comment: i want to know how to use a function with arguments in "onclick" Attribute

Comment: @badr Answer is: You don't. It is almost 100% proof of a really bad design approach if you need that.

Comment: so i just use this.something ?

Comment: I really recommend you stop using index-based loops, the `var` keyword (unless you know exactly why you are using it over `const` or  `let`) and also `element.onevent`-properties. Use the DOM API which offers `element.addEventListener(eventName, handlerFunction)`.

Comment: @connexo, Agreed! I tried to stick to the original code posted by the poster for the sake of the problem faced.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would do this in modern JS:

```js
for (const button of document.querySelectorAll('button'))
  button.addEventListener('click', function() { console.log(this.id) })
```

```html
<button id='b1'>Click</button>
<button id='b2'>Click</button>
<button id='b3'>Click</button>
<button id='b4'>Click</button>
```

Explanation:

When you register a regular `function()` as an event listener and it gets executed because the event occurs, the `this` keyword inside the function will point to the element that the listener was registered on.

Comment: Btw, I haven't used a single index-based for-loop in the past 3 years, and I do web development as a professional on a daily basis. I recommend you dig into `forEach` and `for...of` loops.

Comment: i will do that, Thanks For Helping

Answer (score 0):

Okay, update the code to use with `querySelectorAll` and `forEach`, might help you to understand.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((button)=>{
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){
   console.log(this.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<button id='b1'>Click</button>
<button id='b2'>Click</button>
<button id='b3'>Click</button>
<button id='b4'>Click</button>
```

Comment: Usage of inline event listeners is really bad coding practice, please don't suggest that to someone that has already passed that stage of noob coding.

Comment: i want to use a function with arguments in the "onclick" that's what i want to know how

Answer (score -1):

You can get your button elements length and iterate through your buttons.

I would recommend creating a class for something like this, so instead of just take all buttons give the buttons you would like to involve in this the same **class**.

Here is a way you can do it.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <button id='b1' class="btnWithID">Click</button>
    <button id='b2' class="btnWithID">Click</button>
    <button id='b3' class="btnWithID">Click</button>
    <button id='b4' class="btnWithID">Click</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    function show_id(){
        alert(this.id)
    }


    let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btnWithID');
    for(i=0; i < btns.length ;i++){

        btns[i].onclick = show_id;

    }


    </script>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: when i run it it alerts all the classes but nothing shows when i click them

Comment: Sorry with the argumentation it will applied to all of the 4 buttons I was a bit missleaded.
I have updated my answer now

Comment: someone already wrote the same answer, but thanks anyways.

Comment: and there's no need for a class i think, you can just `querySelectorAll('button')` or `getElementByTagName('button')`

Comment: Probably you dont want to call that function for every button on your site just for a specific amount of buttons. Thats why I would recommend to use classes.